# Explaining a differentiability theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity, intuition

I found the following theorem while reading my calculus notes:

**Theorem**

A real function $f$ is differentiable at some point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ iff there exists  an open interval $I$ and a function $F:I\to\mathbb{R}$ such that, $a\in I$, $f$ is defined on $I$, $F$ is continuous at $a$, and $$f(x)=F(x)(x-a)+f(a)$$ is satisfied by every $x\in I$. In such case, $F(a)=f'(a)$.

In summary, $F(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ with $x\neq a$. $F$ is continuous at $x=a$ iff $f$ is derivable at $x=a$

---

I've trying to grasp its meaning but I don't really understand the previous theorem. Anyone cares to explain?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For intuition maybe you could look at the mean value theorem?

Comment: If $f(\cdot)$ is differentiable at $a$. We then know that it's continuous at that point, this is equivalent to say that there exists an interval $I$ containing $a$ for which $f(\cdot)$ is continuous. With this in mind, we can construct the function $F(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ in $I$,  which is going to be continous in $I \setminus \{ a \}$. You should be able to prove that its in fact continous in $I$ given that $f(\cdot)$ is differentiable at $a$. On the other hand, if you have $F(x)$ continous at $a$ its direct to prove that $f(\cdot)$ is differentiable there.

Comment: Think of the derivative as a slope then the expression $F(x)(x-a) + f(a)$ can be interpreted as the tangent line through $(a,f(a))$ so the theorem says a function is differentiable if it can be perfectly approximated by its tangent line at every point on the interval.

Comment: I don't know standard it is, but I have always known this result as Hadamard's Lemma. It gives a quick proof that the composition of differentiable functions is again differentiable, plus the chain rule (avoiding epsilons and deltas -- provided one has basic results about continuous functions).